# Could a Vulcan pass as a Romulan?

Tags: star-trek

So I've got a Vulcan character who rejects her heritage later in her life. Can't tell you why, because spoilers.

I want her to pass as a Romulan, but I'm not sure if it's doable. Has it been done before?

Comment: Depends on which version of Romulan you mean. TOS..absolutely, TNG,..maybe...others probably not so much.

Comment: Spock hides on Vulcan for a considerable amount of time

Comment: @Valorum But he wasn't *passing* as I recall...he was actually hiding....or do I have that wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I remember a Vulcan pretending to be a Romulan in TNG.

Comment: Without the forehead *adjustment* that everyone else needed?

Comment: @MrLister: There was a Romulan spy pretending to be a Vulcan.  There was also Simon Tarses but he was only a quarter Romulan.  I don't think the forehead ridges were a universal Romulan trait, perhaps only a sub-racial variance.

Comment: There was [Tallera](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/tallera), a Romulan who turned out to be a Vulcan isolationist named T'Paal, in the TNG 2-parter Gambit ([part I](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Gambit,_Part_I_%28episode%29), [part II](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Gambit,_Part_II_%28episode%29)).

Comment: @MrLister - There's no good indication that she lived on Romulus, is there? She just tells people she's a Romulan and they kinda accept it

Comment: sounds like this is about either RPG or fan-fiction authoring...vtc. At minimum, the question should be re-worded to ask if such a thing has happened in any official Trek materials, which would make it on-topic. Otherwise, it's all opinion-based and unanswerable

Comment: @Valorum -- You mean Spock hid on **Romulus**...

Comment: This is an okay question, but it should drop the irrelevant preamble.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I strongly suspect that's what I meant

Comment: @NKCampbell: Fanfic authoring questions are on-topic to the extent that they are asking about canon, which this (mostly) is.  It would be better if it were asking if Vulcans *have actually* passed as Romulans, however (OP: hint, hint), because otherwise it's a rather speculative question.

Comment: It's on topic to ask about fan-fic that has already been written / published, not to ask for help in writing your own characters @Kevin  (which I why I don't vtc all the harry potter fan fic questions....as much as I'd want to ;)

Comment: No, Romulans and Vulcans look nothing alike. A Vulcan could easily pass for a Gorn or the Crystalline Entity, though.

Comment: @NKCampbell: "I'm editing a fanfic and I need to know whether X is true in canon" is on-topic without the part before the "and."  Extra information does not turn an on-topic question into an off-topic question, so it's still on-topic *with* the part before the "and."

Comment: @Kevin - at the time I was making that statement, the question had not been edited. The edit now makes it on topic

Answer (score 5):

In a word, yes. There are a few of instances where Vulcans have been able to successfully infiltrate Romulan society and live among Romulans without arousing (immediate) suspicion. Note, however that in every case they're ultimately caught.

---

In the episodes [TNG: Unification, Part I and Part II](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unification_I_(episode)) we see Spock walking around in public surrounded by a crowd of unsuspecting Romulans. The picture below was apparently taken with the equivalent of a long lens implying that he's been going around with his head uncovered. Obviously if he was recognisable as a Vulcan he'd have been immediately denounced and arrested.

[image]

In the TOS comic [Blood Fever](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Blood_Fever_(comic)) we meet Xon, ostensibly a Romulan scientist but in reality a Vulcan intelligence agent. The crew of the ship that's supporting his science experiments are oblivious to his true nature.

[image]

In the Star Trek novel [Shards and Shadows](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shards_and_Shadows) we encounter Selar, a Vulcan who's been physically altered to look Romulan and has been posing as a Romulan on Romulus for multiple years. Note that this is a Mirror Universe story so the usual rules may not apply.

> She closed her eyes a moment in irritation and then composed herself.
>   Then she turned her attention back to the woman standing before her.
>   “Selar. Your name is Selar. And you’re a Vulcan.”
>
> “There is no logical reason to deny that which you have already, and
>   rudely, discerned.”
>
> “But why? Why hide what you are?”
>
> Selar hesitated but then clearly decided that there was no point in
>   prevaricating. “I am part of an underground group,” she said. “Spies,
>   for lack of a better word. Since Romulans are nominally allies of the
>   Alliance, I have more latitude for movement within the Alliance, and
>   on Romulus, as one of…you.”
>
> “Vulcans spying on the Alliance? Why?”

Comment: there's no indication in the episode that Spock is impersonating a Romulan though. He is there specifically to 'preach' a Vulcan message to Romulans. Anyone that is aware of his presence knows he is Vulcan

Comment: @NKCampbell - He's walking around openly in public. If he was recognisable as a Vulcan he'd be immediately denounced and arrested.

Comment: @valorum Is it illegal for Vulcans to be on Romulus?

Comment: @AzorAhai  - My guess would be yes. Spock, at the very least is an expert in Romulan affairs and a Starfleet officer. That'd make him prime spy material

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for the situation of a Vulcan as a Romulan and came across the opposite first.

[Talok](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Talok) was a long-term, deep-cover Romulan operative who posed as a Vulcan military officer in the 22nd century. (ENT: Episode 4x09 "Kir'Shara")

And after further research you have [T'Paal](http://memory-alpha.com/wiki/T%27Paal_(isolationist)) in TNG episode 7x05 "Gambit,Part II".  T'Paal is played by Robin Curtis and was a Vulcan female who in 2369 posed as a Romulan mercenary by the name of "Tallera"

So yes, a Vulcan can pass as a Romulan

Comment: You're probably thinking of the TNG two-parter "Unification", when Spock visited Romulus.

Comment: There are multiple examples of Romulans passing as Vulcans. Just because one can pass as the other doesn't mean that the opposite is true.

Comment: @Valorum well further research found the answer

Comment: @jedicurt - She appears to be passing as a Romulan *among non-Romulans*.

Comment: @jedicurt - she only passed as a Romulan to a band of mercenary pirates, hardly valid judges to determine. I went back to look at the script to confirm that she did claim herself as a Romulan because prior to that point, she references logic and is portrayed very Vulcan-esque (in fact, she does, however, only in her statements to Picard when she reveals herself as Vulcan) So, it could be that she lied to Picard about claiming to be Romulan to further her lie about being a Vulcan agent. Or, the performance could have played more Vulcan simply because Robin Curtis

Answer (score -1):

Coming at this from the opposite perspective, 'vulcan' [ambassador T Pel](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/T%27Pel_(Ambassador)) was a romulan who passed herself off as vulcan. I would assume during her time in the federation she probably was checked by a doctor at least once without being detected as a romulan.

Another partial example is [Simon Tarses](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Simon_Tarses), a crew member who lied and said in his starfleet application that he was a quarter vulcan when in reality he was a quarter romulan. He was caught based on a background investigation, not a medical investigation, so genetically the species seem to be too similar to differentiate.

Cultural differences and mental discipline would be the key differences I think.

Comment: As I said in my comment above, what you have in these examples are Romulans passing for Vulcans, a very different prospect than a Vulcan passing as a Romulan. We know from TNG + DS9 that unless someone is a Starfleet officer, the prospect of being medically scanned/blood tested is relatively rare and considered an infringement of liberty that one can refuse.

Comment: Given that there was no medical surgery to disguise them, I don't agree there is a difference going one way vs the other. It's not two completely separate species like Klingon to cardassian.

Comment: Actually you don't know what medicalooks interventions were used to disguise T'Pel and Simon Tarses was only a quarter Romulan, far enough different that his genetics are pretty jumbled.

Comment: Genetically the species are the same. The Romulans are the ones that left Vulcan at the time of Sarek.

Comment: Right, from my perspective it frames the question more in the context of "Could a vulcan act in a way that other Romulans wouldn't notice the cultural and linguistic differences between them" as opposed to how well two distinct species can disguise themselves as the other, which I think is an important frame to make.